# MVVM layer between view model and model?

Tags: mvvm

My application must support different UI’s (Win Forms and WPF). This means I have to encapsulate the business logic.
How would you do this?

E.g. WPF with MVVM:

1) Should I introduce a layer between my model classes ( e.g. car, door,…) and the viewmodels? For example by control classes, manager classes, or service classes??

2) Or should the model classes ( e.g. car, door,…)  itself contain the logic?

Answer (score 0):

Model classes typically are used to transfer data to and from whatever UI layer you have and your business logic.  So they generally shouldn't contain any logic.

I haven't tried supporting both WPF and winforms (and can't honestly come up with a single reason why this would be necessary), but AFAICT winforms doesn't support MVVM well at all.  Yeah, you can do bindings (sort of), but you can't, for example, bind ICommands to buttons.

So, I'd suggest using the ViewModel as a bridge between your UI and your business logic.  Then, share the business logic classes themselves between applications.  Your view models should be very thin and relatively easy to create and maintain.  A similar bridge may be useful in the winforms project, or perhaps just simply re-create your view model code in codebehind.

Comment: Thanks! In your opinion how should a business logic should look like when the model classes do not contain the logic? Do you mean something like a service or a control class having all the logic and are operating on dumb models?

Comment: @user3084486 Your logic classes take in arguments and return results.  The arguments and results are your models, the logic resides in the method's body.  A model could be as simple as an integer, or something complex like a Person that has properties and relations to other instances of other types.  The design flows naturally.

Comment: @user3084486 just like in any other program--grab an instance and call methods on it.  How you do this depends on what flavor of application you make.  Now stop dillydallying and go make it!